# How can I create a pixelate interface in android?

Tags: android

I want to create an android app, a tamagochi to be more specific. For that i need to create a pixelated interface. How can I simulate a "big pixel" and how can I animate the "big pixels"?

Comment: What kind of animation do you need? How fast animations should be rendered (fps)?

Answer (score 0):

In my knowledge, there is no such API out of the box.
Building your own system should be fairly simple.

I would store actual low resolution pixels in a `Matrix` and then use this `Matrix` to draw rectangles in View's `onDraw` method. This drawing involves some very simple math used to calculate position and size of your "big pixels" (rectangles) on the screen.